# Adding a new container to Magento 2 header-wrapper for main navigation

Tags: magento2, static-block, navigation, containers

I'm trying to add a new container to Magento 2 and have a main navigation menu displayed in here (which I've created as a frontend block) then trying to add it to my own container where I can add a class to it. I've already set all that up and placed a red border around my new container with that class. I've been able to do that by adding it to my default.xml file for my theme but for some reason I can't get it moved into my header-wrapper area. I basically want it positioned in the same "container" as the logo and floated right, so it's directly across from the logo. Right now though it's only under the container.

[image]

Here is the code I have to add it to my pages:

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
            <container name="main-navigation" as="main-navigation" label="Page Custom Content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="main-navigation">
                <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="main.nav" before="logo">
                    <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">main_navigation</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
```

Is there a way to get it inside the .page-header__panel .container like where the logo is right now? I've tried referencing other containers but they aren't located where I'd like.

How I know where I'd like my main_navigation frontend block is I've located the Magento_Theme's default.xml and it shows where to logo is placed here:

The dashed blue line indicates the container I want it in:

```
<referenceContainer name="header.container">
            <container name="header.panel.wrapper" htmlClass="panel wrapper" htmlTag="div" before="-">
                <container name="header.panel" label="Page Header Panel" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="panel header">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="skip_to_content" template="Magento_Theme::html/skip.phtml">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="target" xsi:type="string">contentarea</argument>
                            <argument name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Skip to Content</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="switch/languages.phtml"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="top.links">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </container>
            </container>
            <container name="header-wrapper" label="Page Header" as="header-wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header content">
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo" name="logo">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">189</argument>
                        <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">64</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
```

So my assumption is that if I wanted my main_navigation block next to the logo is that I would place it in the "header-wrapper" container. Right?

Any help is appreciated.

*** UPDATED ***

After the suggestion from Abhishek, I place the code into my child themes default.xml file and my entire header disappears.

This is the code:

```
<referenceContainer name="header.container">
    <container name="header.panel.wrapper" htmlClass="panel wrapper" htmlTag="div" before="-">
        <container name="header.panel" label="Page Header Panel" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="panel header">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="skip_to_content" template="Magento_Theme::html/skip.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="target" xsi:type="string">contentarea</argument>
                    <argument name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Skip to Content</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="switch/languages.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="top.links">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>
    </container>
    <container name="header-wrapper" label="Page Header" as="header-wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header content">
        <container name="new-container" as="new-container" label="new container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="new-container">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo" name="logo">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">189</argument>
                    <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">64</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>
        <container name="main-navigation" as="main-navigation" label="Page Custom Content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="main-navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="main.nav" before="logo">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">main_navigation</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

And this is what the top of my site looks like now.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try below code. I created another container inside main container and move your container. Now you have to set Design accordingly.

```
<referenceContainer name="header.container">
    <container name="header.panel.wrapper" htmlClass="panel wrapper" htmlTag="div" before="-">
        <container name="header.panel" label="Page Header Panel" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="panel header">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="skip_to_content" template="Magento_Theme::html/skip.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="target" xsi:type="string">contentarea</argument>
                    <argument name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Skip to Content</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="switch/languages.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="top.links">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>
    </container>
    <container name="header-wrapper" label="Page Header" as="header-wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header content">
        <container name="new-container" as="new-container" label="new container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="new-container">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo" name="logo">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">189</argument>
                    <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">64</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>
        <container name="main-navigation" as="main-navigation" label="Page Custom Content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="main-navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="main.nav" before="logo">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">main_navigation</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've added this code to my child themes default.xml but then my whole header disappears. Any ideas as to why it might be doing that?

Comment: what do you mean whole header disappear?

Comment: I'v updated my question. Take a look and see what I mean. Thanks!